# How to make a StackPanel fit its Children's width

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm writing down here because I'm having lots of issues with this thing, and I hope you will be able to help me out :P

I want to create a dynamic StackPanel that fits all its Children's width. I'll make you an example.

Let's say my StackPanel is currently empty. Its Width will be 10 (f.e.) and its fixed Height is 30. Then I want to add an Image, and I wrote this down:

```
BitmapImage myImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri("[PATH]"));
Image realImage = new Image();
realImage.Source = myImage;
realImage.Width = 50;
realImage.Height = myImage.Height;
myStackPanel.Children.Add(realImage);
```

The StackPanel does not enlarge to 50px though; it's stuck to 10px, cutting my image. the same happens when I try to add other UI Elements, like TextBlocks and so on.

I tried to do something like

```
myStackPanel.Width += realImage.Width;
```

But of course it didn't work. I've tried to set the StackPanel's Width to "Auto", but it didn't help either. This is the StackPanel declaration in the XAML:

```
<Window x:Name="MainWindow1" x:Class="Proj.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="myTitle" Height="480" Width="640"
    Loaded="onLoad" Background="Black" MinHeight="480" MinWidth="640">
    <Grid>
        ...(Other Closed Tags)...
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="myStackPanel" Height="30" Margin="135,283,458,147"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I need a StackPanel because I have to show a dynamic bar with a variable number of objects that will perform a marquee effect on the screen, sliding from right to left. I don't know neither the number of the objects nor the final width of my dynamic bar.

Of course, if you know there is an other way to do it, I'll be glad to learn something about it :)

Thank you!

Comment: Set `StackPanel` width to `auto`..I guess that should help

Comment: It was already written in the post that I tried it and it didn't work :P

Comment: There are not enough details. Please post surrounding XAML with all relevant styles and such. Your panel is probably constrained by parent controls. Reading about panels behavior can also help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx

Comment: You are probably right, I didn't post the rest of the XAML because I didn't think it was helpful, but now I edited it.

Comment: The problem is your `Margin` - you are constraining the control to a tiny box on the screen. Check my answer with the fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your stackpanel into a ScrollViewer and set its width to Auto:

```
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel  Width="Auto">
            ....
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: I tried and it actually works, thank you. I suppose that is because this way the StackPanel is inheriting the width of its Parent. Am I right? It's not exactly what I wanted, but it helps a little bit. Thank you again.

Comment: Actually it is not inheriting the Width of the parent, but it's available size depends on it's parent.

Comment: Don't know why a scrollviewer would help here (is it just to provide the marquee effect?) - the `StackPanel` set to `auto` width will always stretch to exactly fit it's children - it will NOT fill the parent container like `Grid` does, only fit the immediate children. By the XAML posted above it looks like the control has a `MinWidth` of 640. I can't comment on the `Margin` though - I'd suspect this has something to do with your problem

Comment: Most likely you are right. But I'm not sure about the MinWidth. After all, it is applied on my Main Window, and it shouldn't affect the Elements inside. Is there another way to give objects a position in the window without using Margins? EDIT: Just saw your answer, I'm gonna try :)

Answer (score 1):

I've just checked and yes, your problem is `Margin`. Do NOT use `Margin` for absolute positioning in layouts. `Margin` should be used as a margin offset from the parent control, but should be avoided when trying to position elements (such as placing an item in the centre of a form) as it clips the elements to a particular bounds.

The effect you want is easily achieved with an `auto` width `StackPanel`

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Name="myStackPanel" Height="30">
        <Button>Hello</Button>
        <Button>World</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Obviously - if you need to position this in a particular place in your window, you need to ensure that it has the full container width available - use `HorizontalAlignment` and `Grid` to place your controls

From your layout I'd suggest something more like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1.4*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Name="myStackPanel">
        <Button>Hello</Button>
        <Button>World</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I'd avoid giving elements explicit sizes unless absolutely necessary - if your parent container can dictate the size, then all the better

If you want the images horizontally aligned within the `StackPanel`, you can set `HorizontalAlignment` to `Center`

Comment: This is actually nice! :) But I'm having an issue: when the objects in the StackPanel exceed the Screen Width, I can't get them at all :(

Comment: Yup, beautiful.  A Grid will fill itself to the parent  (and from there, I could define three columns of width "*" to make them all the same width).  Genial !

Comment: Only took 2 years to get a +1 on this :D